# How can the overlay be styled for AutoCompleteTextField using flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, material-design

I have a page in the Flutter app that uses an AutoCompleteTextField and while I can style the items displayed I have failed to find out how to apply some styling to the overlay itself.

Searching has not revealed any examples of how to do this.

Comment: autocomplete_textfield: ^1.6.4

Comment: use `flutter_typeahead` instead - it is much easier and yet more customizable